# How to create screen form in Informix SQL?

Tags: informix

I am new to Informix-SQL. I am trying to create form in Informix. I referred to [some resources online](http://www.informixoncampus.org/TopicsandLab/2.4c_Informix_Application_Development_4GL_Lab.pdf%20and%20http://userweb.port.ac.uk/~msm/docs/informix/form.html)

This is how I am accessing my database at the moment `dbaccess database_name`. I can't see the 'form' menu for me to create the form. I am an absolute beginner. I would appreciate it if someone could guide me to the right direction (correct commands that I should run and documentations that I can refer to). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DB-Access program is not ISQL.  Indeed, the main distinguishing feature of DB-Access compared with ISQL is precisely that DB-Access does not support reports or forms.

To create forms, you need the development version of Informix SQL, and you either run the `isql` program (choose the Forms option, and then Generate, and follow the prompts), or you run the `sformbld` program with options to create a default form:

```
sformbld -d formname database table1 ...
```

Either way, you normally end up editing, often extensively, the form source file (`.per` extension, for the Perform (aka `sperform`) program which will run it).  Use the plain text editor of your choice (`vim`, `emacs`, `pico`, etc - anything that's OK for C code will work for ISQL too.

---

> What is the difference between `isql` and `sformbld`?

```
$ ls -il isql sformbld sperform saceprep sacego
212302 -rwxr-xr-x 5 informix informix 844005 2010-09-17 11:24 isql
212302 -rwxr-xr-x 5 informix informix 844005 2010-09-17 11:24 sacego
212302 -rwxr-xr-x 5 informix informix 844005 2010-09-17 11:24 saceprep
212302 -rwxr-xr-x 5 informix informix 844005 2010-09-17 11:24 sformbld
212302 -rwxr-xr-x 5 informix informix 844005 2010-09-17 11:24 sperform
$
```

Different names for the same executable.  However, the executable behaves differently depending on the name it is invoked by.  When invoked as `sformbld`, it compiles forms; with the `-d` option, it generates a form and then compiles it.  When invoked as `sperform`, it runs a form.  When invoked as `saceprep`, it compiles an ACE report; when invoked as `sacego`, it runs a report.  (The '`s`' prefix indicates the SQL version of ACE and Perform (and FormBuild); when it was first released in 1985, there was also a non-SQL product called Informix 3.30 with these programs as part of the suite.)

When invoked as `isql`, the program behaves as an interactive menu IDE for creating and running forms and reports - unless invoked with options to make it run a form or compile a report or whatever.

```
isql -fc form    # Compile form
isql -fr form    # Run form
isql -rc report  # Compile report
isql -rr report  # Run report

isql dbase [-|script]   # Runs SQL script, rather like DB-Access does
```

(Actually, once upon an evening back in the very early 90s - or perhaps very late 80s - DB-Access was created by stripping unneeded code from ISQL.  So, DB-Access behaves like ISQL does, rather than vice versa.)

Comment: That's really fast response. Do you happen to know what is the difference between sformbld and isql?

Comment: do you know how i can hide .sql scripts from users, while isql -qr script.sql can still execute them?.. i tried setting the hidden attribute on the .sql files, but isql bombed out.

Comment: No - I don't think there's a way to do that - doubly not on a Windows platform.  On Unix, you could play silly games with SUID programs, and redirect the `.sql` file as standard input, etc, but that might not be the result you're looking for either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Interesting edit in your answer about DB-Access, but I didn't see any DB-Access in my ISQL 4.10 (1991).. I was thinking since one cannot hide .sql scripts in isql, perhaps using symbolic links (win-vista/7 supports them), it could be done?

Comment: DB-Access is primarily distributed with the servers - not with ISQL.  And IIRC, it was first released with OnLine 5.00 and SE 5.00.  In the most recent versions of CSDK, I believe it is now available there too.